# Как остановить клонирование элементов?

Tags: javascript, css

Как остановить клонирование элементов когда их количество достигнет например 3?
https://jsfiddle.net/z2o9u0kb/7/

```
<button class="add-shape-btn">Add shape</button>

<div class="box__row box__row--1">
  <div class="shape shape--other"></div>
</div>
<div class="box__row box__row--2">
  <div class="shape shape--default"></div>
</div>

const buttonAdd = document.querySelector('.add-shape-btn')
const parentOther = document.querySelector('.box__row--1')
const parentDefault = document.querySelector('.box__row--2')
const shapeOther = document.querySelector('.shape--other')
const shapeDefault = document.querySelector('.shape--default')

buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let cloneOther = shapeOther.cloneNode()
  parentOther.appendChild(cloneOther)

  let cloneDefault = shapeDefault.cloneNode()
  parentDefault.appendChild(cloneDefault)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.shape--other').length > 2)
  return;
```

Comment: что-то не хочет работать

Comment: @Sergey Что не хочет работать? Мне сквозь монитор плохо видно, что Вы сделали. Вероятно, неаккуратно скопировали мой код.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, можно просто использовать свойство `children` родительских элементов, проверяя размер коллекции (то есть, количество непосредственно дочерних элементов):

```
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const childCount = Math.max(parentOther.children.length, parentDefault.children.length); 
  if (childCount < 3) {
    parentOther.appendChild(shapeOther.cloneNode()); 
    parentDefault.appendChild(shapeDefault.cloneNode()); 
  }
});
```

Или, можно считать нажатия кнопки (сохраняя значение счетчика, например, в ее data-атрибуте):

```
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  const clickCount = evt.target.dataset.clicks = ~~evt.target.dataset.clicks + 1;
  if (clickCount < 3) {
    parentOther.appendChild(shapeOther.cloneNode()); 
    parentDefault.appendChild(shapeDefault.cloneNode()); 
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Сделал вот так

```
let count = 1
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let cloneOther = shapeOther.cloneNode()
    let cloneDefault = shapeDefault.cloneNode()

    if(count++ < 4) {
        parentOther.appendChild(cloneOther)
        parentDefault.appendChild(cloneDefault)
    }
})
```

Comment: зачем клонировать узлы, если выражение явно ложно?